# How do I set <table> border width with CSS?

Tags: html, css

Why does this work?

```
<table border=1>
```

And this doesn't?

```
<table style="border-width:1px;border-color:black">
```

I get the same result in Chrome and in IE9.

Answer (score 111, accepted):

Doing borders on tables with css is a bit more complicated (but not as much, see [this jsfiddle as example](http://jsfiddle.net/uzxWp/)):

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

table td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for fixing my post. Also, your css works great.  It is just frustrating that they don't simplify the syntax.
All three of your styles were necessary and sufficient to accomplish my goal. Thank you!

Comment: is there any reason not to use this:
table, td {border: 1px solid black;}
It seems to work without any need for border-collapse.

Comment: depending on what exactly you're trying to achive: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/css/css_border-collapse.htm

Comment: but this applies the style for every table in the page. isn't it possible to specify a style by table ?

Comment: @v.oddou specify some tables by class (`table.someclass`), or one table by id (`table#someid`).

Comment: what effecte does `border-collapse: collapse;` have?

Answer (score 15):

The default `border-style` is `none`, so you must specify that as well as the width and the colour.

You can use the `border` shorthand property to set all three values in one go.

Also, the border attribute describes the border for the table **and** the cells. CSS is much more flexible so it only describes the border of the elements you are selecting. You need to select the cells too in order to get the same effect.

```
table, th, td {
    border: solid black 1px;
}
```

See also [border properties](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#border-properties) and [tables in CSS](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html).

Comment: Thanks. Interestingly, adding border-style:solid to my css gave the table the same exact appearance as using oezi's css, even though it doesn't specify border-collapse, but oezi's css requires it.

Comment: Don't forget to use "border-collapse: collapse", this will prevent your border to have a double since table, tr and td will have border.

Answer (score 7):

The reason it didn't work is that despite setting the `border-width` and the `border-color` you didn't specify the `border-style`:

```
<table style="border-width:1px;border-color:black;border-style:solid;">
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Thn9x/).

It's usually better to define the styles in the stylesheet (so that all elements are styled without having to find, and change, every element's `style` attribute):

```
table {
    border-color: #000;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    /* or, of course,
    border: 1px solid #000;
    */
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Thn9x/2/) ([Or using shorthand `border` notation](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Thn9x/3/)).

Comment: Thanks, you answered all of my questions and the demo is great. I actually am working with a stylesheet but wrote the question as inline (I tried both with the same result).

Comment: You're absolutely welcome; I'm glad to have been of help! =) Incidentally, if you feel that your question has been answered please consider accepting (clicking on the `✔` below the vote-counts) the answer which was most helpful to you.

Answer (score 3):

```
<table style='border:1px solid black'>
    <tr>
        <td>Derp</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This should work. I use the shorthand syntax for borders.

Comment: &lt;table style='border:1px solid black'&rt; does add borders around the whole table, but not around the individual cells.  Still, this is certainly better than nothing. Thank you so much.  I am giving oezi my vote though, because he not only fixed my post but his css is perfect.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add border-style like this:

```
<table style="border:1px solid black">
```

or like this:

```
<table style="border-width:1px;border-color:black;border-style:solid;">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<table style="border: 5px solid black">
```

This only adds a border around the table.

If you want same border through CSS then add this rule:

```
table tr td { border: 5px solid black; }
```

and one thing for HTML table to avoid spaces

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
border: 1px solid black;
```

Why it didn't work? because:

> Always declare the border-style (solid in my example) property before the border-width
>   property. An element must have borders before you can change the
>   color.