# Cannot see table borders when using jQuery and Ajax to load PHP echo'ed table

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

So I am learning how to use jQuery, PHP, AJAX, and MySQL. I want to get a table from the MySQL server and display it. To do this I have 2 PHP files, one that is the server-side file that logs in to the MySQL database and echos a html table, and the second that is the index.php file that the user sees. I am using jQuery's ajax load method to update the page when a button is clicked, and return the server-side PHP's echo'ed table. When I do this the table's borders are never loaded. Could someone please help me with this?
[Screen Shot](http://puu.sh/gjCWk/611da7a618.png)

indexTest.php(connects to MySQL server/server-side php file):

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "test";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
else {
$sql = "select name, species from pet";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$counter = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    if ($counter > 0) {
        echo "<table id  = 'pets'>
        <tr>
        <td><strong>names</strong></td>
        <td><strong>species</strong></td>
        </tr>";
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['species'] . "</td>"; 
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";

    }
}
$conn->close();
```

script.js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("button").click(function(){
            $("#fromAjax").load("indexTest.php", true);
        });
});
```

index.php(the one I am loading the table in!):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src='jQuery-2.1.3.js'></script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='script.js'></script>
        <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "stylesheet.css" type = "stylesheet/css"></link>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="myDiv"><p id = "fromAjax">This will be replaced with the Table</p></div>
        <button>Change Content</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

And my CSS:

```
*{
    font-family; "Impact", "Times New Roman";
}
#fromAjax{
    color: red;
}
#pets{
    color: blue;
    border: 5px solid black;
}
```

Comment: Wait, whut? The table's borders are not loaded?

Comment: Yea. Here is a screen shot after I clicked the button to update it: http://puu.sh/gjCWk/611da7a618.png

Comment: Do you have a style for the table? It's id is `#pets` which is a bad idea. You should really remove the hash.

Comment: ID's don't have `#` in them and borders are nothing but a css property. Define a rule for them

Comment: Attach your screenshot to your original post @m0t0. Do you have a rule specified for the table in your CSS? If so, share that too.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I set <table> border width with CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7764553/how-do-i-set-table-border-width-with-css)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in comments mentioned, remove the # from the ID of your table:

```
 echo "<table id  = 'pets'>
```

then add the following CSS

```
#pets td{ border: 5px solid pink; }
```

and you should have a border :-) on your table

Comment: You added the CSS code in your question after I answered. I believe the code you have in your question is set in the document itself and not in a file and therefore overwrites the property set in the CSS file

Comment: You need to give the td elements the border: `#pets td` I changed my answer